# Unable to connect to Azure VM using RDP

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

I have a Windows 10 Azure virtual machine I've been using for more than a year and all of sudden I can no longer connect to it using RDP. I didn't change any configuration or install any software leading up to this issue.

This is what I get when I run the troubleshooter:

[image: Can't Connect to VM]

I'm not sure why the notification banner was being shown. The VM had recently been restarted, but it was not in the process of being stopped at the time I ran the troubleshooter.

I've done everything suggested in the recommended steps including resetting the configuration, resetting the NIC, redeploying, checking the network settings, and checking the firewall settings. I can't see anything that looks wrong, but I still can't connect.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.